# How can I associate a stream (FILE *) with stdout?

Tags: c, io, stream

Right now each module is writing to stderr, thus I cannot turnoff output of an individual one. Does anyone know how I can associate a stream with stdout thus each module will write to independent stream so I can turn it off.  For example:

```
fprintf(newStdout, "hello");
```

`newStdout` is writing to the screen. I don't know how to associate `newStdout` with the screen.

Comment: On Posix, you might be able to use `dup` and `dup2` on the underlying file descriptors (cf. `fileno`) to solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a problem with just `newStdout = stdout` to turn it on, and `newStdout = some_other_file_descriptor` (maybe pointing to /dev/null if your on a unixy system) to turn it off?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I didn't even think of that. It works, just for turning it off make sure to use `fopen`, **not** `freopen` since both point to the stdout thus it would redirect stdout, but fopen won't. If you like post it as an answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is to just have `newStdout` behave like `stdout` some of the time and silence it some of the time, you can do something like this:

```
// Global Variables
FILE * newStdout;
FILE * devNull;

int main()
{
  //Set up our global devNull variable
  devNull = fopen("/dev/null", "w");


  // This output will go to the console like usual
  newStdout = stdout;
  call_something_that_uses_newStdout();


  //This will have no output
  newStdout = devNull;
  call_something_that_uses_newStdout();


  //This will log to a file
  newStdout = fopen("log.txt","w");
  call_something_that_uses_newStdout();
  fclose( newStdout ); // -- If we don't close it here we'll never be able to close it;)

  //Clean up our global devNull
  fclose( devNull );
}
```

Comment: I found the wording of this question and this answer as well thoroughly confusing, however +1 for FILE *fp = stdout. The output does not go nowhere, it goes to standard output, which is the answer I needed!

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/ - Its a C++ reference, but should be valid for C.

```
include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't think you can do this on a per-module basis though, as `stdout` and `stderr` are global variables.

Comment: I've changed your link to another reference, I hope you won't mind :-)

Comment: @Kos Actually the change is inappropriate, as it was as a reference for the example. The example is not from the page you've linked to.

Comment: OK, so I'll just rollback. :) I remember a discussion on SO about meritorical erros on cplusplus.com and it not being up to date, so I try to reference people to cppreference.com instead. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I want to redirect a `FILE *` to `stdout` rather then redirect stdout to a file. I've updated the question