# Redirecting mpirun stdout when using two applications (MIMD)

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am running two applications coupled together using:

`mpirun -np nprocs1 app1 : -np nprocs2 app2`

I want to redirect the stdout from each application separately to a textfile. The best I could do so far is:

`mpirun -output-filename logfile -np nprocs1 app1 : -np nprocs2 app2`

where (nprocs1+nprocs2) files with name logfile.### will be created with each corresponding to a process. But this is tedious since each application's output is spread across many files. It would be great to have a single file for each application. Is there a mpirun flag that will achieve this?

P.S:. Though it would not matter, app1 is written in C and app2 in C++.

Comment: You could alter one of the apps and redirect stdout to your own file, e.g. the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168244/how-can-i-associate-a-stream-file-with-stdout is `freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);` (and you'd need to close it before MPI_Finalize). The problem here is that `mpirun` is clever in the way it collates stdout; if you redirect to a file, all processes will be writing to the same file at the same time without locking so you're likely to get quite a lot of gibberish *unless* only rank 0 does IO ...

Comment: Thanks, David! Mostly the rank 0 writes out stuff but sometimes the other processes will print out some useful stuff as well. I will try this and see.

Comment: An MIMD application is a single MPI job from the point of view of `mpirun` and it has a single collated stdout stream. You may use `mpirun --tag-output` to have each output line prefixed with the rank and job ID and then use `grep` to split the messages from ranks `0` to `nprocs1-1`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Oh, I thought mpirun considers them as two different applications. It makes sense now why they don't have application specific stdout separately. Thanks! I have decided to merge the process-specific output files (using `-output-filename logfile` ) to get what I wanted.

Comment: Although some ranks run `app1` and the rest of the ranks run `app2`, they still belong to a single world communicator and are treated as a single MPI application. If you want to have two separate MPI applications talking to each other, look into using the client/server model (`MPI_Open_port()` / `MPI_Comm_accept()` / `MPI_Comm_connect()`)

Comment: @HristoIliev These are entirely independent apps and they are communicating with each other using the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` when run together this way. And I have created separate communicators for their internal communications using the `MPI_APPNUM` attribute. I think this is appropriate for my purpose as the applications need to run individually by themselves as well. I don't think the client/server model will suit my needs. I am only vaguely familiar with the client/server model but will read up further. Thanks for the helpful tips, though!